Wireframing software handling 3 buttons mouse click
I would like to prototype an application that would be capable of handling 3 buttons mouse clicks, even 4 buttons mice, with different events. It's also known as B1, B2, B3, and B4 clicks.
Example, on a graphical element like a text label, the event triggered by a left-click, right click, or wheel click would trigger different events.
Figma is not capable of doing this, for example. It's only handling "click".
I've found that proto.io is able to handle left-click and right-click.
Could you recommend a software application, that could be a Windows desktop app or a web app, that could do this?
